How to access Firestore Database not Realtime Database
I have a firestore database on my project and want to read/write to it not the ReatlTime Firestore database. I copied the databaseURL which connects to the RealTime database but not the firestore database. When I generated the firebaseConfig object it doesn't contain the a databaseURL attribute. How do I access the firestore database?
Here is my code:
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, db

cred = credentials.Certificate("../../../serviceAccountKey.json")

firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL': 'https://<project-id>-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/'
})

# Now you can interact with the database
ref = db.reference('testName')

print(ref.get())


I upgrades python3 version to 3.12.7 and re-installed firebase-admin and changed the code to this and it worked:
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import firestore

# Use a service account.
cred = credentials.Certificate("../../../serviceAccountKey.json")

app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

db = firestore.client()

users_ref = db.collection("test")
docs = users_ref.stream()

for doc in docs:
    print(f"{doc.id} => {doc.to_dict()}") 


Isn't that pretty much exactly as shown in the quickstart page of the documentation? https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#initialize
